# negative units in itunes connect sales report

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Today I found a -1 in the units column "units" and in the same line a negative full app price next to the normal positive proceeds in the daily sales report in ITC.

Looking around on Google gives no real explanation. (from returned app to Apple correcting sales report numbers)

Anybody knows what this really is?

Many thanks

Comment: so how is it a programming question?

Comment: I think this question fits into both of these: 
# software tools commonly used by programmers
# practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

Comment: Not just a site for programming questions according to FAQ. I think this question fits into both of these: 
`# software tools commonly used by programmers` - ITC is both a web app and an iphone app
`# practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession` - ITC isn't much used by people not in the programming profession

Comment: ITC is also used by everyone publishing music/videos as well, as long as you have a music publisher account

Answer (score 13, accepted):

-1 means that somebody (1 person) requested and achieved a refund on your app.

Comment: Not just a site for programming questions according to [faq]. I think this question fits into both of these: # software tools commonly used by programmers - ITC is both a web app and an iphone app # practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession - ITC isn't much used by people not in the programming profession

Comment: Alright, you convinced me mostly, but ITC is used by everyone publishing music/videos as well, as long as you have a music publisher account.

Comment: I wouldn't condemn a music publisher for using this site to ask this question either ;) Good answer though. **+1**

Comment: Refunds can be related to Complete My Album functionality. Read more about it here:
https://support.tunecore.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006689628-Why-do-I-see-a-negative-sale-for-iTunes-on-my-Monthly-Sales-Report-

Comment: @coneybeare but in some cases I observed that the amount for sale was -0.99 and refund went is -1.09. Is Apple charging their fee too for refund?